# Страница с адаптивной вёрсткой не уменьшается меньше 980px

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Добрый день.

Есть [сайт](http://albatroc.mozwebteam.ru/), делаю для него адаптив. Беда в том, что страница не уменьшается меньше 980px при изменении размера экрана. Фикс высоту убрал, большая часть блоков страницы скрыта.

Причём по ходу не уменьшается сам элемент `<html>` , даже когда через инструменты удалю всё со страницы. Стилей на нём никаких не висит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С ним проблема, а про пустую страницу к тому, что даже пустая страница не становиться меньше 980рх

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83)

Comment: Chromium 60.0.3112.113, [всё адаптируется и влезает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69yxc.png). У вас какая версия обозревателя?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589184/why-does-the-chrome-devtools-responsive-viewport-think-its-980px-wide

Comment: @Arhad наведи на html в коде и посмотри размеры или через JS.

Answer (score 4):

Вам не хватает `meta` тега с `viewport`. По-умолчанию в Webkit ширина страницы на мобильных устройствах [равняется 980px](http://frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport/). Чтобы ширина страницы равнялось ширине экрана нужно добавить следующий тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Про viewport можно почитать подробнее:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/
- http://frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport/
- https://habrahabr.ru/company/paysto/blog/254871/